# Event to detect when the text in an <input> is scrolled?

Tags: javascript, html, events, scroll

Is there an event that is fired when the text inside an `<input>`-tag is scrolled? I mean when the text inside is to long and you move the input caret to the end of it, etc.

There is a `scroll` event you can catch on the element when that is scrolled in the layout, but that is not what I want.

*UPDATE*: Here is a fiddle to test the events discussed: http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/L8k5ggnk/3/

Comment: I am curious what you want to use it for.

Comment: @jbg,  Just a rewrite of complete.ly.js. It uses a "background" `<input>`-tag to display a hint. I want to scroll the text in the hint when the text in the main `<input>` is scrolled.

Comment: An `input` does fire a `scroll` event when the overflowing text "scrolls" via change in overflow, at least in Firefox.

Comment: Oh, interesting @AlexanderO'Mara, I do not see that in Chrome. Is that according to standard, or?

Comment: @Leo I'm not sure, but a `scroll` event doesn't fire in Chrome unfortunately, despite the fact that it has the `scrollLeft` property.

Comment: Here is a reported bug at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1007153, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no specific event for this that will work across browsers. Firefox does fire a `scroll` event when the text "scrolls" by changing the insertion point, but Chrome and likely other browsers don't.

Here is a list of events that could change the insertion point.

- `input`
- `keydown`
- `keyup`
- `focus`
- `blur`
- `click`
- `change`
- `paste`
- `cut`
- `scroll`
- `wheel`
- `dragover`

Binding an event listener to all of these should be enough to respond to the insertion point changing. I believe the list above is complete, but if I have missed any, let me know!

Comment: Thanks, looks good, but some details: Isn't there a `change`event too? And `blur`. (And why is `keydown` needed? And does not the other cover `scroll`?)

Comment: @Leo `change`! How did I miss that? `keydown` is needed to respond to a key being held down, as `keyup` will only fire once when the key is released (not for every time a character is added/removed). You could probably drop scroll, unless there is some reason it scrolls without user input. I'm not sure about `blur`, but I think it might actually be necessary for browser that reset the scroll on blur.

Comment: Missing `paste` & `cut` but they should be covered by `input`. Also missing `dragover`, thought this one is an hard beast: The scrolling will only happen when being over one of the extremities (at least in Chrome), and I don't think there is anything firing when this happens (the only solution I can think of rn would be to poll `selectionStart`...). Also, IE11 and Edge do fire the `scroll` event, but they let `scrollLeft` at `0`, unlike Firefox. And on macOs, you can scroll input using the pointing device, which does only fire a `wheel` event in Chrome, and doesn't modify the selectionStart.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Caret Plugin](http://code.accursoft.com/caret/overview)?

You can get the position of the caret with:

```
pos = $(textarea).caret()
```

and catch when it changes again. If the latter is different than the first then you know the user has moved inside the input.

Comment: Thanks, no, but I am trying to avoid jQuery here. That is so to say one of the points with complete.ly.js ... ;-)

Comment: @Leo the source of the plugin is pretty small, so maybe you can look at it and get some ideas. In fact, as I look at the source, I can notice very little jQuery inside the function itself.

Comment: Thanks, @Hanlet, I took a look, but it does not detect any events. It just sets or gets the caret position.

Comment: Makes sense. Just throwing ideas in here... You could make it work without jQuery, and bind it to the `click`, `focus`, and maybe the `scroll` events. I can't think of any other events where you would want this to work.

Comment: Actually I think `keyup` and `change`events are the ones to look for (if there is no special event, of course).

Comment: Hm, I created a fiddle to test, see edited question. It looks like `keyup`, `input`, `focus` and `blur`can change scrollLeft and are fired in Chrome. But I saw `change` too, didn't I? ;-)